# Is it possible to import different files?

Tags: netlogo

First, I'm sorry if this is a dumb question as I am new to Netlogo.

I've done the butterfly model from Steven Railsback and Volker Grimm book and there is an exercise to import a file that has coordinates X Y and a variable which is elevation in that example. So far, OK. But i'm currently trying to implement a model in which we have 4 different files each one containing the same coordinates but different variables, my question is: Is it possible to import those 4 files and have 4 different variables in our 'environment'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to make sure- you are working with the "ElevationData.txt" file found [here](http://www.railsback-grimm-abm-book.com/downloads.html), correct? So your file reading code should look more or less exactly as shown in the [Railsback and Grimm](https://books.google.ca/books?id=VQOjinaRG9cC&lpg=PP1&dq=Agent-based%20and%20Individual-Based%20modeling&pg=PP1#v=onepage&q=Agent-based%20and%20Individual-Based%20modeling&f=false) book:

```
file-open "ElevationData.txt"                          
  while [not file-at-end?] [
    let next-X file-read                                 
    let next-Y file-read
    let next-elevation file-read                         
    ask patch next-X next-Y [set elevation next-elevation]
  ]
  file-close
```

So if the other files you want to import are mostly identical to the "ElevationData.txt" file, but with a different value in the third column, you can absolutely just modify that chunk of code accordingly. If we are dealing with vegetation cover as an example, you'd need a `patches-own` variable for that, **along with** the `elevation` variable that already exists:

`patches-own [ elevation veg-cover ]`

Now pretend that you have a "VegetationData.txt" file that looks something like:

```
0 0 0.86
1 0 0.15
2 0 0.42
3 0 0.44
4 0 0.43
5 0 0.33
...
```

After you have run your elevation import, you could do the exact same thing but with vegetation:

```
  file-open "VegetationData.txt"                          
  while [not file-at-end?] [
    let next-X file-read                                 
    let next-Y file-read
    let next-veg-cover file-read                         
    ask patch next-X next-Y [set veg-cover next-veg-cover]
  ]
  file-close
```

Now your patches will have a value assigned to both their `elevation` and `veg-cover` variables.

That said, it would be better if possible to combine your input files and load them all together. If you have a combined Elevation and Vegetation text file that looks like:

```
0 0 532.4 0.86
1 0 529.3 0.15
2 0 526 0.42
3 0 520 0.44
4 0 519.5 0.43
5 0 519.3 0.33
...
```

In the combined dataset ("ComboData.txt"), you still have the x and y columns, but now column three is elevation and column four is vegetation cover. Now you can load everything at the same time by slightly modifying your import code:

```
  file-open "ComboData.txt"                          
  while [not file-at-end?] [
    let next-X file-read                                 
    let next-Y file-read
    let next-elev file-read
    let next-veg-cover file-read                         
    ask patch next-X next-Y [
      set elevation next-elev
      set veg-cover next-veg-cover
    ]
  ]
  file-close
```

Comment: I wasn't using those files anymore, but the example you gave answered my question. My point was to know if having two or more different variables in the same patch wouldn't cause any problem. Apparently not. thanks :)